# recommended c# winform controls packs

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Am looking for commercial/free recommended c# winform controls packs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/)**

*I've tried [ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/), DevExpress and [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/)*

Answer (score 4):

See the following threads:

- [.NET Usercontrols telerik devexpress infragistics ComponentOne whos best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169357/net-usercontrols-telerik-devexpress-infragistics-componentone-whos-best#170227)

Answer (score 4):

I've used the controls from both [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/) and [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com) and find the DevExpress ones to be far superior.

Although, my Infragistics exposure was .NET 1.1 and DevExpress has been 1.1 to current.

Edit:

The support available on the DevExpress website has also never failed to solve a problem that I have had, I remember having an issue with the Infragistics grid control and not being able to solve it and believe me, I'm doing a lot more complex stuff with the DevEx stuff currently!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using some lighter weight components from [Component Factory](http://www.componentfactory.com/products.php). They have a free kit, that has spiffed up versions of the basic winform components. As far as I know, they don't have a grid control.

For grids, I've used [SandGrid](http://www.divelements.com/net/controls/sandgrid/) from DivElements.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the Winforms Infragistics controls

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Telerik controls suite, and they are fairly decent.