# How do I make a TabPage's title text bold?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have some tabControl in C# Windows app. It has some tabPages. Does anyone kwows how to make the tabPage Text to become Bold..?

Comment: What do you want to make bold? The tab title, or the contents of the tab page?

Comment: Winform. I want to make bold the tab title.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180563/bold-text-for-a-tab-control

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to handle the `DrawItem` event of the `TabControl` to manually draw the caption. Note: `DrawMode` of affected control should be set to `TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`.

Here is a sample:

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{

    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Brush _TextBrush;

    // Get the item from the collection.
    TabPage _TabPage = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];

    // Get the real bounds for the tab rectangle.
    Rectangle _TabBounds = tabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index);

    if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
    {
        // Draw a different background color, and don't paint a focus rectangle.
        _TextBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds);
    }
    else
    {
        _TextBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
       // e.DrawBackground();
    }

    // Use our own font. Because we CAN.
    Font _TabFont = new Font(e.Font.FontFamily, (float)9, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    //Font fnt = new Font(e.Font.FontFamily, (float)7.5, FontStyle.Bold);

    // Draw string. Center the text.
    StringFormat _StringFlags = new StringFormat();
    _StringFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    _StringFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    g.DrawString(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, _TabFont, _TextBrush,
                 _TabBounds, new StringFormat(_StringFlags));

}
```

Comment: Just to add to this: `DrawMode` of affected control should be set to `TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`, this makes using the `DrawItem`-event mandatory (If you leave code of this method blank, the tabs' title bar will be blank too)

Answer (score 3):

In Winforms you can change the DrawMode and paint all the captions on yourself.

See the [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.drawmode(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Another, less elegant option is to set the font->bold property of the parent form/control to true, which will make everything bold including the tab names and then set bold to false on all the controls you don't want bold.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is an Image of TabPage.Text made Bold and with FontSize 25]

All one has to do is write the main TabControl code as follows:

```
 TabControl0_1=New TabControl

 TabControl0_1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1900,980)

 TabControl0_1.Location=New System.Drawing.Point(5,5)

 TabControl0_1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI",25!, _
                       System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing. _
                       GraphicsUnit.Point,CType(0, Byte))
```

This takes care of everything. There are total 114 TabPages.