# How to increase font size of TabControl item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

In my winform project I need to increase the font size of the `TabControl` items, but if I increase the size, also the content of the `TabControl`changes the own size...
any ideas?

I also want to change the background of the `TabControl` palette *(not the entire tabControl)*.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried updating properties of the `TabPage` (Not `TabControl`)?

Comment: yes, all the `TabPage` increases the size: http://i.imgur.com/jFgAf6r.png

Comment: This might help [Make Tabpage title bold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326406/how-do-i-make-a-tabpages-title-text-bold)

Comment: I think there is similar problem and it has the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953792/how-to-change-size-and-image-in-tabcontrol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the font and back color of tab pages without changing the font and back color of child controls, you should know:

The [`Font`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.font(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`BackColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor(v=vs.110).aspx) properties are  ambient properties.

An ambient property is a control property that, if not set, is retrieved from the parent control. For example, a `Button` will have the same `BackColor` as its parent `Form` by default. For more information about ambient properties, see the [`AmbientProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.ambientproperties(v=vs.110).aspx) class or the Control class overview.

You can set the `Font` and `BackColor` for each tab page explicitly. This way, the child controls of tab pages, use `Font` and `BackColor` of `TabPage`.

You can explicitly set control's ambient properties to prevent them from using parent's property value.

(Thanks to [TaW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784643/how-to-increase-font-size-of-tabcontrol-item#comment57319171_34786360) for better option rather than using panel as container of controls in the tab page.)

Comment: As all content must live inside the TabPages it is enough to set the TabPages' fonts to the smaller size.

Comment: @TaW Great! Yes. You are completely right, `TabPage` is also `Control`  and follows the rule for ambient properties. So it's enough to set the `Font` and `BackColor` for `TabPages`