# Put Bold font in title of tab in a tabcontrol c#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, tabcontrol

I've got this tab control:

[image: tabcontrol2]

I need to put the tab name "Notes" in a bold font but I don't know how to.

I tried this code:

```
tabControl2.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

However, it put all tabs in bold. Then I tried this:

```
tabControl2.TabPages["Notes"].Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

I also tried this : 
[How do I make a TabPage's title text bold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326406/how-do-i-make-a-tabpages-title-text-bold)

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Brush _TextBrush;

            // Get the item from the collection.
            TabPage _TabPage = tabControl2.TabPages["Notes"];

            // Get the real bounds for the tab rectangle.
            Rectangle _TabBounds = tabControl2.GetTabRect(1);

            _TextBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);

            // Use our own font. Because we CAN.
            Font _TabFont = new Font(e.Font.FontFamily, (float)9, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            // Draw string. Center the text.
            StringFormat _StringFlags = new StringFormat();
            _StringFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            _StringFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            g.DrawString(tabControl2.TabPages["Notes"].Text, _TabFont, _TextBrush, _TabBounds, new StringFormat(_StringFlags));
```

However, it put all the content of the tab in bold and not the title. I don't know how to put the title of this specific tabpage. Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't think there is much support for customising the actually tabs themselves. I think you may need to look into the render or paint event and handle the drawing yourself. [This article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91387/Painting-Your-Own-Tabs-Second-Edition) is a bit OTT for your needs but should have all the info you need to handle the custom drawing of the text

Comment: Seems it's [not easy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2326406/1997232).

Comment: You say the duplicate question put ALL the text in bold, but I don't see that from that answers code. I don't think you are doing it right. You must have something else that is making everything else bold

Comment: @musefan I said duplicate question do anything in my case, I edit the question with my code.

Comment: Ok, I have re-opened it as you have put enough to specifically say it's not a duplicate, however I am not really seeing the problem myself. That code is only drawing the title text. It wont effect the rest of the text on the page

Comment: hmm... using that code, you need to set `DrawMode` of the tabcontrol to `OwnerDrawFixed` for the event to fire

Answer (score 2):

I hope I can be of any help to you.

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tabControl.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        tabControl.DrawItem += TabControlOnDrawItem;
    }

    private FontStyle HasNotification(string tabText)
    {
        return tabText.Equals("Notes") && true 
                   ? FontStyle.Bold
                   : FontStyle.Regular;
    }

    private void TabControlOnDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var tab = (TabControl) sender;

        var tabText = tab.TabPages[e.Index].Text;

        e.Graphics
         .DrawString(tabText
                     , new Font(tab.Font.FontFamily
                                , tab.Font.Size
                                , HasNotification(tabText))
                     , Brushes.Black
                     , e.Bounds
                     , new StringFormat
                       {
                           Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                           LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                       });
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to change tabControl.SizeMode to Fixed and increase tabControl.ItemSize.Width because when some text became bold, the increased width caused it to wrap to a new line inside the tab.