# Free winforms packs / controls

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Where can I find a list of freely available controls for winforms? 
[recommended c# winform controls packs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178661/recommended-c-sharp-winform-controls-packs) -this list have only premium controls that cost a lot! Help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you check out the DevExpress controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevExpress offers a free package of some of their controls for WinForms and ASP.Net. I believe it's still available. You can get them [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/NetOffer/).